# How can I vectorize these while and nested for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vectorization, evaluation

I am trying to vectorize the following code. My program is taking quite a long time to execute the result.  For that reason i want to vectorized my while loop.  Is it possible to vectorize it or do you have a different idea on what I should do?

Here I am taking the average of the neighboring pixels and iterating the loop until I get an approximate result:

```
n = 500;
Mat_new = rand(n); 
error = 1;
while error > 0.000001
    Mat_Old = Mat_new;
    for i = 2:n-1
        for j = 2:n-1
            Mat_new(i,j) =abs((2+((Mat_Old(i+1,j)+Mat_Old(i-1,j)+Mat_Old(i,j+1)+Mat_Old(i,j-1))))/(4));
        end
    end
    error =max(max(abs(Mat_Old-Mat_new)));
end
```

Comment: Read up on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945579/can-anyone-help-me-to-vectorise-this-for-loop-i-am-running-this-loop-for-n-numb

Comment: have you considered using the build in filters, like fspecial http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/fspecial.html

Comment: Or convolution ['conv2'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html).

Comment: I assume you try to simulate diffusion with the border as constant constraints?

Comment: i do not want to use the boundary pixels like my loop will consider 2 to n-1. could you tell me how i can over come this problem.......

Comment: @user2851655 - Caveat.  This `while` loop will only converge if the error is less than a certain amount.  Perhaps the error is **never** going to be less than this amount, which is why the loop isn't converging?  Perhaps change your error threshold so that it's larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially a convolution of a 2D matrix.  You just have to specify the input filter that you want.  In your case, you want find a weighted sum of the base cardinal directions: North, East, South, West, given a particular location in the matrix as the output.  As such, create a 3 x 3 filter that encompasses these directions, then use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html), or [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) to create your output matrix.  Seeing as how you want to create an image that has 1 element border surrounding the result, we should use `conv2` instead.  Though you have a lot of parentheses (yuck), what (I believe) you are doing is adding up all of the values in the cardinal directions, add this sum with 2, take the absolute value, then divide by 4.

As such, do this:

```
n = 500;
Mat_new = rand(n); 
error = 1;
h = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]; % // Define filter here
while error > 0.000001
    Mat_Old = Mat_new;

    Mat_new = conv2(Mat_Old, h, 'valid');
    Mat_new = abs(Mat_new + 2) / 4; %//Take the output, add 2, absolute then divide by 4
    %// Pad border with zeroes
    Mat_new = padarray(Mat_new, [1 1]);

    error = max(abs(Mat_Old(:) - Mat_new(:))); %// Calculate maximum error
end
```

What the above code is doing is basically what you're doing with the double `for` loop.  Except now, we are doing it with `conv2`.  The first line of `Mat_new` computes the sum of the four cardinal directions for each location in your matrix, ignoring the border as you have shown in your `for` loop.  Once we do this, we take the absolute value of each entry in the matrix through `abs` after we add 2 to each entry, then divide by 4.  After, we pad the border of the output matrix with all zeroes using [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html).  By the way, I've restructured your `error` statement so that it doesn't use a nested call to `max`.  I never liked the way that looked.

Unfortunately, the `while` loop (I don't think...) can be vectorized.  You are computing a new output at each iteration, and want to calculate the error between the previous iteration and the current one.  In this case, there is no way to vectorize something like this with a strong recurrence relation.... so you're stuck with the `while` loop for now.  However, you can definitely vectorize the double `for` loop, and that's what we have just accomplished.

This should hopefully achieve what you want!

Comment: Dear Rayryeng. thanks a lot. but here i try to simplified my code and i cannot use a filter as i need to add some noise at each point. but by the way this is also an grate idea...........

Comment: Can't you just add the noise to each point before or after you run it through convolution?  You didn't make that very clear.  Please modify your question to reflect this information.

Comment: But here it also consider the boundary pixels.. like in my case its n-2 but here it will use all the pixels.......

Comment: @user2851655 - In that case, use `conv2` with the `valid` flag, then pad the border with zeroes.  I'll edit my post

Comment: @user2851655 - Oh your'e welcome!  What about the noise issue you're speaking of?  Did you get that resolved?